# How do I change an index value in a Multi-index Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

[image: If you look at the above image, the level 0 index (3, 102483) are random numbers. And this goes on until the end of the dataset. I want to be able to change these numbers to be from 0,1,2,3 so on. So 3 would be 0 and so on]I have a data frame with a multi index and I wanted to change the values on one of them.

For example:

```
index = [1,23,356,405,513,65,6787,898,679]
index_2 = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
names= ["James","Adam","Mary","Tom","Sam","Harry","Jacob","Isa","Rick"]

df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=names, index=[index, index_2])
```

This will give me a data frame with two indices. "Index" are random numbers such as the above. However I want to change the index to default values such that it takes values from 0,1,2,3 so on instead of the random numbers above.

I am doing it with a very large dataset which has random numbering to the data and I want to change it to have default index numbers from 0,1,2 and so on.

So my question is, how do I replace the values with a default index?

Comment: to avoid confusion, do u mind posting the expected output

Comment: I edited my original post to incorporate an image and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `df_test` exist already, you can set the index with [pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) and get the `codes` from the original index level you want to replace by incremental value and `get_level_values` for the other one.

```
# assume df_test created like this 
index = [1,1,356,356,356,6787,6787,6787,6787] #change this to be more like your problem
index_2 = ["A","B","C","D","E","A","B","C","D"]
names= ["James","Adam","Mary","Tom","Sam","Harry","Jacob","Isa","Rick"]

df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=names, index=[index, index_2])
print (df_test)
            0
1    A  James
     B   Adam
356  C   Mary
     D    Tom
     E    Sam
6787 A  Harry
     B  Jacob
     C    Isa
     D   Rick

# so you can do to have regular incremental for first level of index
df_test.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df_test.index.codes[0], 
                                           df_test.index.get_level_values(1)])
print (df_test)
         0
0 A  James
  B   Adam
1 C   Mary
  D    Tom
  E    Sam
2 A  Harry
  B  Jacob
  C    Isa
  D   Rick
```

Comment: I edited my original post to explain exactly what I expect my output to be. Hope it clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a range with the length of the data to your index:

```py
range_1 = list(range(len(names)))
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=[names], index=[range_1, index_2])
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what u r after, a visual of ur expected output would be helpful :

```
#drop the index with the random numbers
df_test = df_test.droplevel(0)
#get the indices for the letters
#assumption here is that the letters r not repeated
new_index = df_test.index.get_indexer_for(df_test.index)

#if the letters are not unique :
from itertools import chain, islice
c = chain.from_iterable
e = enumerate
#this allows us to pull the unique numbers per letter
new_index = islice(c(e(df_test.index)),0,None,2)

#assign the new index, and set it as the outermost index
df_test.set_index(new_index,append=True).swaplevel(1,0)
```

Comment: I have edited the original post with a visual and my expected output. I essentially want the 3 of the index to be 0.... and so on.